C++ setvbuf and sync_with_stdio(false);
I use CLion and if I don't have the line
setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);

I don't get output in the console when debugging.
But I also use:
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  std::cin.tie(nullptr);

for faster I/O operations.
However if I have both it doesn't print output again during debugging. Is there any way to fix this? More importantly:
  setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

These two lines clash with eachother, not std::cin.tie(nullptr);.

"for faster I/O operations" - and why would you do that? Do you have repeated and interleaved std::cin and std::cout in your code? If it affects the performance, maybe it would be easier to simply fix the design, e.g. by first reading required inputs, then computing, and then printing the results.

So is I/O particularly slow on your system? Have you measured the improvement that sync_with_stdio and tie give you? Is it worth it? Basically you seem to be saying you want faster I/O while simultaneously complaining about the consequences of that. Decide what's important to you and stick with it. I know which I would pick.

So sync == false means that some operations are not properly synched. Surprise!

@john yes I have measured I do tests with large amount of data and it does help significantly printing certain things out. I'm not too familiar with setvbuf, so that's why I asked here to find a solution some middle ground if there isn't a replacement for setvbuf.

@pptaszni in most cases they're not interleaved

During debugging, don't do that.  Just do it for release mode when you need the significant improvement in printing certain things out.
